# Neurological response to food cravings caused by bacteria

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, gut-bacteria

Our microbiome [(Kurzgesagt video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzPD009qTN4) is thought to send our brain information to chose certain foods to eat over others and it's our increase in a certain type of bacteria that will form a stronger craving for whatever that bacteria happens to appreciate the most. 
I'd like to know more about how the brain makes those choices in relation to the bacteria, than in relation to a general reward (The brain receives dopamine for things that are achieved, how does bacteria affect that?). Do the bacteria affect the amount of dopamine released- if so then how are the neurons that appreciate that bacteria award, broken or less interested when another type of bacteria now wants a different type of food?

**NOTE** Neurons are formed when the brain "achieves something" like when bacteria are given the food they thrive on I suppose, so when another type of bacteria receives more food and takes over in your gut, how is it that your neurons are broken and seemingly replaced? I understand this is a stretch but bare with me I just spoke to a neuroscientist about a month back who informed me about the basics of this process.